# How to cancel MediaWiki's password reset’s email count?

Tags: email, mediawiki, password-reset

If you use **Special:PasswordReset** more than once for the same username/e-mail address, then https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgPasswordReminderResendTime dictates you’ll get `"A password reset email has already been sent, within the last 24 hours. To prevent abuse, only one password reset email will be sent per 24 hours."`

But that user lost their message and I need to let them regenerate it.

How can I reset the count, probably through the database?

Comment: Questions about setup and configuration of web applications on your own server are off-topic on this site. Please ask in [meta.se] if there is a site for questions like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [user_newpass_time](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_table#user_newpass_time), e.g. `UPDATE user SET user_newpass_time = 20000101000000' WHERE user_name = '...';`